# RSA algorithm in the SSL

Tags: rsa

I want to know about the explanation of RSA, here is the example

```
Select primes: p=17 & q=11
Compute n = pq =17×11=187
Compute ø(n)=(p–1)(q-1)=16×10=160
Select e : gcd(e,160)=1; choose e=7
Determine d: de=1 mod 160 and d < 160 Value is d=23 since 23×7=161= 10×160+1
Publish public key KU={7,187}
Keep secret private key KR={23,17,11}
```

Look at the prime numbers written above, how can i know from where those prime numbers are generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those prime numbers can be generated randomly by the RSA algorithm. In this example they are very small, but in real life the would be very very large. The algorithm will also take some other precautions when generating the primes. For instance, p and q should not be close to one another.

Comment: In the example it is written that lets take a example of Message "M" and M=55 is the message converted to a integer number, if yes how computer convert a number in to integer, rather than computer convert everything to ANSI code.

Comment: you mean to say that the example M=55 is the conversion of unicode of our message

Comment: @Rain, no. That's just a made up example. In real life, however, it would likely be encoded using some Unicode encoding.

Comment: So, i want to know that how our message convert to integer, because integer cant be devided by a ASCII code or any Hex number,octal number.

Comment: Why not? "Hi" might turn into H=74, i=105, so "Hi"=074105. Certainly that number can undergo any arithmetic required by RSA. This is an example of using ASCII as an encoding: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: last question, who choose the prime numbers. You wrote that those number are generated by randomly, when it the number generated process is going on.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that implements RSA

```
try out this code

/*Arpana*/

#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<math.h> 
#include<string.h> 

long int p,q,n,t,flag,e[100],d[100],temp[100],j,m[100],en[100],i; 
char msg[100]; 
int prime(long int); 
void ce(); 
long int cd(long int); 
void encrypt(); 
void decrypt(); 
void main() 
{ 
clrscr(); 
printf("\nENTER FIRST PRIME NUMBER\n"); 
scanf("%d",&p); 
flag=prime(p); 
if(flag==0) 
{ 
    printf("\nWRONG INPUT\n"); 
    getch(); 
    exit(1); 
} 
printf("\nENTER ANOTHER PRIME NUMBER\n"); 
scanf("%d",&q); 
flag=prime(q); 
if(flag==0||p==q) 
{ 
    printf("\nWRONG INPUT\n"); 
    getch(); 
    exit(1); 
} 
printf("\nENTER MESSAGE\n"); 
fflush(stdin); 
scanf("%s",msg); 
for(i=0;msg[i]!=NULL;i++) 
m[i]=msg[i]; 
n=p*q; 
t=(p-1)*(q-1); 
ce(); 
printf("\nPOSSIBLE VALUES OF e AND d ARE\n"); 
for(i=0;i<j-1;i++) 
printf("\n%ld\t%ld",e[i],d[i]); 
encrypt(); 
decrypt(); 
getch(); 
} 
int prime(long int pr) 
{ 
int i; 
j=sqrt(pr); 
for(i=2;i<=j;i++) 
{ 
    if(pr%i==0) 
    return 0; 
} 
return 1; 
} 
void ce() 
{ 
int k; 
k=0; 
for(i=2;i<t;i++) 
{ 
    if(t%i==0) 
    continue; 
    flag=prime(i); 
    if(flag==1&&i!=p&&i!=q) 
    { 
        e[k]=i; 
        flag=cd(e[k]); 
        if(flag>0) 
        { 
            d[k]=flag; 
            k++; 
        } 
        if(k==99) 
        break; 
    } 
} 
} 
long int cd(long int x) 
{ 
long int k=1; 
while(1) 
{ 
    k=k+t; 
    if(k%x==0) 
    return(k/x); 
} 
} 
void encrypt() 
{ 
long int pt,ct,key=e[0],k,len; 
i=0; 
len=strlen(msg); 
while(i!=len) 
{ 
    pt=m[i]; 
    pt=pt-96; 
    k=1; 
    for(j=0;j<key;j++) 
    { 
        k=k*pt; 
        k=k%n; 
    } 
    temp[i]=k; 
    ct=k+96; 
    en[i]=ct; 
    i++; 
} 
en[i]=-1; 
printf("\nTHE ENCRYPTED MESSAGE IS\n"); 
for(i=0;en[i]!=-1;i++) 
printf("%c",en[i]); 
} 
void decrypt() 
{ 
long int pt,ct,key=d[0],k; 
i=0; 
while(en[i]!=-1) 
{ 
    ct=temp[i]; 
    k=1; 
    for(j=0;j<key;j++) 
    { 
        k=k*ct; 
        k=k%n; 
    } 
    pt=k+96; 
    m[i]=pt; 
    i++; 
} 
m[i]=-1; 
printf("\nTHE DECRYPTED MESSAGE IS\n"); 
for(i=0;m[i]!=-1;i++) 
printf("%c",m[i]); 
}
```